# callgrind equivalent for java?

Tags: java, runtime, callgrind

Is there a **free** callgrind equivalent for java? basically, i just need anything that gives me cycle counts or time spent for each method and function of my java code.

i suppose i should mention i'm using mac, which means the eclipse thing below doesn't work for me, i believe.

Comment: if i knew any i wouldn't be asking the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you could start with Sun's [Java VisualVM](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html) application profiling.

Comment: It's part of the Java6 JDK distribution

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

http://eclipsecolorer.sourceforge.net/index_profiler.html